# excel vba form submit and parse data from result

Tags: html, excel, parsing, vba

here's my code, unfortunately do to company issues i can't post the real url, it works but not the way i want, check my question below:

```
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
Dim r As Long

Sub ficfinder()
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL:="...INPUT"<---this is my search form, but i have to redact due to co policy
    Do 'Until .readyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    'pick field to fill out
    Set mytextfield1 = .document.all.Item("WESTAC")
    'set value to put in
    mytextfield1.Value = "5416869160"
    'click the submit button
    IE.document.all.Item("Submit").Click
    Do 'Until .readyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    End With
'I think i'm missing something here

    Set doc = IE.document
    Dim sdd As String
    Set TDelements = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    r = 0
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        If TDelement.Align = "right" Then
            Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.innerText
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

so this works and puts data into my spreadsheet, but the data it is pulling is from the search form, not the page that comes up after you submit.  how do i make IE.document the new page that comes up??

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you put a break on the `Do` (right after submitting the form) can you see the page refresh in IE?  If you then hit "continue" in the VB Editor do you get the expected results?

Comment: yes, that makes the data correct!  so do i need to put a wait in before the do?

Comment: A wait would probably do it.

Comment: can you suggest the code for the wait here?  everything i'm trying is throwing me an end with error

Comment: never mind, figured it out.  thanks for your help.

Comment: I added 

    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

just after the submit and it works perfectly.  Thanks to Tim Williams for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

just after the submit and it works perfectly.  Thanks to Tim Williams for the help!