# Multiple form submit and parse data from result page

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, screen-scraping

I have  a web page which has multiple form. Every submitted form opens a new page. I’m trying to fetch data from  these pages. With below code i can open pages but the data is pulling from the form page, not the pages that comes up after you submit.

I looked this solution but it doesn’t work in my case.

[excel vba form submit and parse data from result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300576/excel-vba-form-submit-and-parse-data-from-result)

Here is my code;

```
Set formsw = IE.document.forms
For Each form In formsw
    For Each elem In form.elements
        If elem.Value = "Show Summary (Html)" Then elem.Click

            Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

            Sheet1.Activate
            Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents

            r = 0
            For Each TRelement In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TR")
                  Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TRelement.innerText
                  r = r + 1
            Next
        End If
   Next
Next

Set form = Nothing
```

Here is part of source;

```
    <input class="newInputButton"  type="button"  name="btnSubmit" width="100%"     value="Show Summary (Html)" onclick="javascript:form1.action='/BEP/ShowApproved?w=0';      form1.target='_blank';    form1.submit();">
    <input class="newInputButton" type="button"  name="btnSubmit" width="100%"  value=""Show Details (Html)" onclick="javascript: form1.action='/BEP/ShowApproved?w=0';         form1.target='_blank';    form1.submit();">
    <input class="newInputButton"  type="button"  name="btnSubmit" width="100%"     value="Show Summary (Html)" onclick="javascript:form2.action='/BEP/ShowApproved?w=0';      form2.target='_blank';    form2.submit();">
    <input class="newInputButton" type="button"  name="btnSubmit" width="100%"  value=""Show Details (Html)" onclick="javascript: form2.action='/BEP/ShowApproved?w=0';         form2.target='_blank';    form2.submit();">
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to focus IE on the new web page.  The following code counts all open instances of IE and retrieves their url and title.  If there are some characteristic words in the url or title of your new web page, then you can use them below to get the macro to control the new page.  This example uses the page title, but you could use the url just as well.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If my_title Like "Some characteristic words from your new web page" Then 'find the new web page
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next
```