# Excel VBA automation of html form generated by php

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am a non-coder/programmer trying to create an excel spreadsheet that utilizes some VBA automation to import some web-data based on certain cell values. I have managed to scrape together part of the process using Youtube and some other sites like this. However, I have hit a road block that I am hoping someone could help me with.

Here is the setup:
I am trying to import some Co2 data based on 2 parameters (pressure and temperature) that will reside in 2 separate cells in my excel sheet.
In my VBA code, I have managed to navigate to the first site (http://www.peacesoftware.de/einigewerte/co2_e.html), and then find the table elements, fill them in, and submit the form.
My problem is when IE navigates to the next page where the results are. I do not know how to import table elements from this new page. I assume I need to tell VBA to look at the new page, but it has a generic URL (http://www.peacesoftware.de/einigewerte/calc_co2.php5), so I am confused on what to reference.
I hope this is all the info needed to get a clear picture of my problem. Here is my current VBA code. The end  part after "submit" is a wild guess on my part. Once VBA is looking at the right table/page, I will then import the enthalpy and entropy values to my excel spreadsheet.
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
' updates enthalpy, entropy data from peacesoftware site
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Row = Range("tempA").Row And Target.Column = Range("tempA").Column Then
 Dim IE As Object
 Dim pressA As String
 Dim tempA As String
 Dim denseA As String
 Dim enthA As String
 Dim entroA As Style

  tempA = Range("tempA")
  pressA = Range("pressA")
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
' setup internet explorer
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "http://www.peacesoftware.de/einigewerte/co2_e.html"
Do
  DoEvents
  Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  ' find pressure and temp entry form
  IE.document.getElementsByName("druck")(0).Value = pressA
  IE.document.getElementsByName("temperatur")(0).Value = tempA
  IE.document.forms(0).submit
  'Do
  'DoEvents
  'Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  'update new energy data
  'IE.navigate table_url ???
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

***Update

I think I found a solution, so I can at least get it functional. (thanks to this post: [excel vba form submit and parse data from result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300576/excel-vba-form-submit-and-parse-data-from-result?rq=1) )

I needed to wait after submit and then search for the "td" element I needed. Since the actual value I needed was the next element after the element label, I used TDelement.nextElementSibling.innerText to grab it.

```
IE.document.forms(0).submit
  ' wait for new page to load
  Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

  Set doc = IE.document
    Dim sdd As String
    Set TDelements = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    r = 0
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        If TDelement.innerText = "Density : " Then
            Range("denseA") = TDelement.nextElementSibling.innerText
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form is sent by POST and not by GET.
That means that you cannot see/manipulate/send the parameters in the URL.

BUT you can use VBA to send a POST-Request directly to the result page.
The following code gets you the values you mentioned in the commenct-section of this response.
You have to change the postData-variable if you want another temperature or 'druck':
This Example-Code just gives you the result for the values 20 and 20.

```
    Dim Density As String
Dim Entropy As String
Dim Enthalpy As String
Dim SoA As String

Dim Result As String
Dim myURL As String, postData As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

myURL = "http://www.peacesoftware.de/einigewerte/calc_co2.php5"
postData = "lang=english&calc=standard&druck=20&druckunit=1&temperatur=20&tempunit=1"

winHttpReq.Open "POST", myURL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpReq.Send (postData)

Result = winHttpReq.responseText

Density = getValue("Density", Result, False)
Entropy = getValue("Entropy", Result, False)
Enthalpy = getValue("Enthalpy", Result, False)
SoA = getValue("state of aggregation", Result, True)
```

Additionally I created a helper-function which must also be implemented:

```
Public Function getValue(Property As String, Result As String, isBold As Boolean) As String

    Dim posProp As Long
    Dim posTD As Long
    Dim posEndTD As Long
    Dim startPosVal As Long
    Dim endPosVal As Long
    Dim valLength As Long
    Dim Value As String

    'find the position of the value on the page
    posProp = InStr(1, Result, Property)

    If posProp > 0 Then

        posTD = InStr(posProp, Result, "<td>")

        If isBold = True Then
            posEndTD = InStr(posTD, Result, "</b></td>")
            startPosVal = posTD + 7
        Else
            posEndTD = InStr(posTD, Result, "</td>")
            startPosVal = posTD + 4
        End If

        endPosVal = posEndTD
        valLength = endPosVal - startPosVal

        Value = Mid(Result, startPosVal, valLength)
        getValue = Value
    End If

End Function
```

Hope this helps!

If you need any help just leave me a comment.

EDIT:
Ah i just read that you found a solution.
But I think this code is a bit cleaner and faster because it just send ONE http-request directly to the result-page.

Comment: thanks for the response user3170197, this method seems to return just the first column of the results table. I think I may have stumbled upon a solution, of which I will update my original post. (Also, I am sure what I have is clumsy and slow I may try and streamline it after I get it working)

Comment: Hi Ryan, this Method returns the WHOLE html-Code. It does just not fit into the msgbox. Which values do you want to get out of the table? All of them or just some?

Comment: I am looking for density, entropy, and enthalpy from the table. As you can see I am very green! I had a sneeking suspicion there was a better way to do this. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thank you for your work!! I am using your method and am finding it is much faster. However, I added a phase property and now when I import the value into a cell the result is <b>value</b>. I can see this is because your code is looking between td elements, but I cannot figure out how to account for when an element has a bold tag.

Comment: I don't really get whtat you mean with 'I added a phase property'.

Comment: Oops, I meant that I am looking at the "state of aggregation" property in the results table. In the page source code it looks like any result that is a string is bolded, so it has the <b></b> tags on it. They are showing up in my cell as well as the string value.

Comment: I changed the code: Added an isBold parameter to the function. Don't forget do add the parameter on the existing function calls.

See updated answer